# Not able to create logs on CD server in sitecore 9.1

Tags: upgrade, logging

I have upgraded Sitecore 8.1 to 9.1 and have different servers for each environment , but the CD server is not generating logs in the data folder , I have given the path of the data folder in the `DataFolder.Config` file and `Sitecore.Config` file also, still not able to see the logs there, Please help.

Comment: needs some more details. could you please share DataFolder.Config file as a screenshot? It could be a misspelling issue as an example.

Comment: Do you use Application Insights maybe?

Comment: Double check the file system permissions.  I ran into an the issue once because the account that the app pool was running under didn't have permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore 9 default location of logs was changed. Instead of having data folder on same level as website folder, logs were moved under website folder.

You can check *App_Data\logs* folder inside your website, logs should be there if you have default logs configuration.